# Shortest declaration of the read/write property in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I need a few public properties, in C# I will do this way.

```
public VendorOrderService { get; set; }
```

What is the shortest (correct/idiomatic) syntax for such properties in F#?

```
member val VendorService = Unchecked.defaultof<VendorOrderService> with get, set
```

P.S. I do understand that public properties are not super idiomatic for F#. But this code is working in larger .NET project, so such properties are obligatory.

Comment: Unchecked.defaultof<> is probably not idiomatic. I'd put an init value in the constructor.

Comment: `type Person { mutable Age : int }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type Foo() =
     member val Text : string = null with get, set
```

Comment: How is that shorter (except for `null`, which is awful, and hopefully his types are not nullable)?

Answer (score 5):

First of all in C# you should write type, like this

```
public string VendorOrderService { get; set; }
```

In F# 3.0 you can use [val keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469494.aspx) (just like you are):

```
type MyType() = 
    member val VendorOrderService = "" with get, set
```

or use [[CLIMutable]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289724.aspx) attribute:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type MyType = { VendorOrderService:string}
```